# How do I get the drag results when dragging to the desktop?

Tags: c#

When I drag a file to the desktop the drag succeeds. I know that simply by checking. But I want the program to know that. But - `DragDropEffects` is always `None`.

Answer (score 0):

`DragDrop.DoDragDrop` can do this as long as you pass it an appropriate `DataObject`.

First copy the files somewhere. You can use `System.IO.Path.GetTempPath()` if you don't have anywhere better.

Next create a string array containing the full paths to the files and do the following:

```
string[] paths = ...;
DragDrop.DoDragDrop(this, new DataObject(DataFormats.FileDrop, paths),
                    DragDropEffects.Copy);
```

`DragDrop` will return [DragDropEffects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dragdrop.dodragdrop%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which is the final result of the `DragDrop`.

Comment: I have that (Except the DragDrop.DoDragDrop - What’s that?), remember the drag works.

Comment: @Anonymous: See here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dragdrop.dodragdrop.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the help. 
Sorry to burden, but I can’t seem to get your example working, even after referring to PresentationCore.dll and WindowsBase.dll.
I get an error message for the `this`. I tried replacing it with `new System.Windows.DependencyObject()` but still get an error message: "The scope must be a UIElement or ContentElement."